# How do I add mySQL JDBC Driver when creating a Driver definition?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, web, driver

I am currently trying to make a connection to a database through a dynamic java web application in eclipse. I found this helpful [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6NQtfokZr8) and while I am trying to follow it, I have ran into an issue.

This led me to more research where I found this [link](https://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/add-mysql-jdbc-driver-to-eclipse.html)

At Step 5 when he clicks on MySql, it presents him with drivers to the mySql JDBC Driver versions. However when I do this, there is nothing there. I cannot add the jar connector file without clicking on a version but there are no versions to click. I have not been able to find an answer to how to fix this, and would appreciate the help if anyone has any. I have provided a screenshot of what my page looks like below. [image: When trying to add a driver:][image]

Answer (score 1):

When I installed Eclipse, I had to go download the MySQL driver.  Depending on which version of MySQL you are working with, you might want a different version.

For MySQL 8.x use this link:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

For MySQL 5.x use the same link, but click the Archives tab and select one of the 5.1.x driver jar files.

Once downloaded, in Eclipse in your last image, click the Jar List tab.
[image: Click the tab labelled Jar List (orange arrow)]

If there is already a jar listed, click and edit it to provide the path to the downloaded jar.  Otherwise, just add the jar.

It might be an issue with the Eclipse Data Tools Platform.  Go to About Eclipse and click the Installation Details button.  Once there click on the Plug-ins tab and search for mysql.  Here is what I see:
[image]

If yours looks similar, you might just need to update.  Go to the Installed Software tab and click the Update... button.  If they are not there, you may need to get an updated version of Eclipse or you might be able to search for them in the marketplace.  Under the help menu click Eclipse Marketplace... link and search there.  Good luck!

Comment: It won't allow me to add the jar file until I click on a version type. Therefore, clicking the JAR List gives me no options

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the tutorial carefully, you should first click the **[Add]** button in "**Driver Defintiions**" dialog, then you can use the Vendor Filter to select the **Available driver templates** for **MySQL**.[image]

Comment: This still shows no options. I have added another screenshot to the post to show...